# Responsive design doesn't work on wordpress

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am creating WP theme with responsive layout based on twitter bootstrap. You can see the website on [panel.daweb.cz](http://panel.daweb.cz) everything work fine.. when you reduce size of your browser, the site changes layout for other devices... but when you load the same website on other devices (e.g. iphone, phones with android) so responsive design doesn't work. I have done HTML copy of this site on [vectoryl.vacau.com](http://vectoryl.vacau.com) and there responsive design works on pc well and on other devices too. Here is my function.php https://gist.github.com/2568852 .If you would need post any another piece of code no problem.

Pls does someone know what is wrong? I am really hopeless.

Thanks for your time and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the meta viewport element in the  to tell the devices to scale the layout to the device width.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```